# three.js: BufferGeometry and textures

Tags: javascript, three.js, buffer-geometry

I'm trying to load textures on a `THREE.BufferGeometry`, but the texture isn't showing up.  If I use normal geometry, the texture shows up.  Are textures unsupported with BufferGeometry or am I doing something wrong?

**This works:**

```
var geom = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1);
var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("texture.png");
var mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map:texture, side:THREE.DoubleSide });
scene.add( new THREE.Mesh(geom, mat) );
```

**This doesn't:**

```
var geom = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1);
var buffgeom = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
buffgeom.fromGeometry(geom);
var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("texture.png");
var mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map:texture, side:THREE.DoubleSide });
scene.add( new THREE.Mesh(buffgeom, mat) );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a bug in r68's BufferGeometry.fromGeometry().

Its been fixed in r69dev already.